# Repeating characters when attempting to concatenate man pages to plain text files

Tags: bash, manpage

I tried converting some man pages to plain text files. But when I open the file, many of the words have unnecessary repeating characters.

For example doing `man awk > awk.txt` changes the sections in the awk.txt file from:

- **NAME** to **NNAAMMEE**
- **SYNOPSIS** to **SSYYNNOOPPSSIISS**
- **DESCRIPTION** to **DDEESSCCRRIIPPTTIIOONN**

I thought this would be a simple task. Why does this happen?

Comment: try `man -ascii awk > awk.txt`. (doesn't work on all systems, may need `--ascii`). Look at `man man` for other ideas. I'm going to bed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man pages contain *formating information* (for instance to indicate if some words should be bold). Consequently, some characters may appear repeated when redirecting the output in a file.

You may want to try:

```
man awk | col -b > awk.txt
```

What col is doing:

> **col — filter reverse line feeds from input**
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> col [-bfhpx] [-l num]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The col utility filters out reverse (and half reverse) line feeds so that the output is in the correct order with only forward and half
>   forward line feeds, and
>        replaces white-space characters with tabs where possible.  This can be useful in processing the output of nroff(1) and tbl(1).
>
> The col utility reads from the standard input and writes to the standard output.
>
> The options are as follows:
>
> **-b**      Do not output any backspaces, printing only the last character written to each column position.